# Reflecting UIView changes after drawing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uibezierpath

How can I reflect UIView changes of a `setNeedsDisplay`?

In `drawRect` triggered by `setNeedsDisplay`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
   double i = 0;
   for(...)
   //i is incremented
       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(i * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                drawStuff(element, context);
       });
```

For example, each draw update would happen after 1s, 2s, 3s, ...

`DrawStuff` switches back to the main thread with

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) { ...
```

when updating the UI. I have tried both `UIBezierPath` and *Core Graphics* and get the same results. I am also using `UIGraphicsPushContext` and `UIGraphicsPopContext` to get the correct context.

Using NSLog, I can tell the drawStuff is called in the 1s increments. However, the visible UIView remains unchanged. I can rotate the device screen and this will reposition the UIView and change its size. On rotation the UIView will reflect what it has currently drawn, but then I need to rotate it again to see the updated state after a few seconds.

Back to the question above, is there a call to tell UIView to display its current graphics after `setNeedsDisplay`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make sure your view is redrawn once per second, the right way to do this is to set some form of timer *elsewhere* in your view, and have the timer function call `-setNeedsDisplay`. This will in turn invalidate your view and cause your `-drawRect:` to be called, which should do the drawing (ie call your `drawStuff`)

Conceptually, `-drawRect:` should only be a dumb method that just knows how to do the actual drawing work based on whatever the current state of the view is. Your normal event logic (or a timer) outside of that should (a) update the state as necessary and (b) mark the view as needing to be redrawn.